# JSF @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped calling priority

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Is there any difference in writing scope and bean annotation in any particular sequence in JSF ? For eg. see the below two declaration

@SessionScoped

@ManagedBean(name = "editEmployeeController")

or

@ManagedBean(name = "editEmployeeController")

@SessionScoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the same. There isn't any priority. 
But this is best practice from oracle for the order.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#orderoftags

Comment: actually my list was not populated in UI while i was writing @SessionScoped

@ManagedBean(name = "editEmployeeController") but when I interchaged the sequence then it populated.

Comment: Same import? There are two packages javax.enterprise.context and javax.faces.bean

Comment: Ok I got it.. There was some other issue with the list.. Thanks for the help